# How to query all the details of the Contact at once

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

EDIT:A list of what I consider important contact details:

```
1.NAME
2.PHONE NUMBER
3.EMAIL ADDRESS
4.WEBSITE
5.PHYSICAL ADDRESS
```

I would prefer to do this using a pre-fetched contactId...using only one cursor to get all of the data specified.I,preferably would like to find the right query to do this:

I would like to get all of the important details of a Contact at once,I am using the following code to do this:

```
       public void getAllDataByContactId(int contactId)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Seriously scared it might not work");
    String phoneNo="Phone disconnected";
    String email="Email could not be delivered";
    String website="Website 404";
    String address="Number 13,Dark Street,Area 51,Bermuda Trianlge";
    String name="Clint Eastwood";
    int hasPhoneNumber;
    String selection=ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+"=?";
    String[] selectionArgs={String.valueOf(contactId)};
    Cursor c=context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,selection, selectionArgs,ContactsContract.Data.TIMES_CONTACTED);

    if(c!=null && c.getCount()>0)
    {

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {

            phoneNo=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Log.d(TAG, "Phone number: "+phoneNo);
            email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
            Log.d(TAG, "Email: "+email);
            website=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL));
            Log.d(TAG, "Website :"+website);
            address=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
            name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.d(TAG, "Name :"+name);
        }
    }   
}
```

However,although this does not throw an error it shows many rows consisting of an empty string interspresed with the actual values.How do I write a query that cuts out the noise?

I have tried this and this gets me all the values:

```
             String selection=ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+"=? AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=? OR "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=? OR "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=? OR "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=? OR "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=?";
    String[] selectionArgs={String.valueOf(contactId),ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
```

Comment: have u done it dear...

Comment: Are you essentially saying that I need to use more than multiple cursors in order to retreive the data I need to get(phone number,email,website...) and storing the data in a wrapper.Is there a way of obtaining the data by tweaking the selection clause mentioned at the end of the post?

Comment: from this way u get dear i follow same 4 contact

Comment: But wouldnt that mean 1 cursor for phones,one cursor for emails,one cursor for websites etc...i believe that data from various tables can be displayed at one using SQL...can this be done using a single cursor...I have conveniance methods for getting all the details using a cursor each per item.

Comment: dear i use only one plzz see my code carefully

Comment: I want everything at once,you would have to use a different Cursor with ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI for email etc.http://pastebin.com/Kcv4ySZ7

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer, but maybe it can help someone in the future.
My solution for this question with only one while cycle and query:

```java
private void fetchContacts(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        if (contentResolver == null) return;

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        String prevId = "";
        String contactId = "";
        PersonContact personContact = null;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String company = "";
            String columnName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype"));
            if (columnName.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                company = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
            }

            String email = "";
            if (columnName.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            }
            String phone = "";
            if (columnName.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
            }
            String first = "";
            String last = "";
            if (columnName.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                first = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data2"));
                last = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data3"));
            }

            if (!prevId.equals(contactId)) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(prevId)) {
                    addFilteredList(personContact);
                    allContacts.put(prevId, personContact);
                }
                prevId = contactId;
                personContact = new PersonContact();
            } else {
                if (personContact != null) {
                    personContact.id = prevId;
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(personContact.company)) personContact.company = company;
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(personContact.firstName)) personContact.firstName = first;
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(personContact.lastName)) personContact.lastName = last;
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && personContact.emails.size() == 0) {
                        personContact.emails.add(email);
                    }
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone) && personContact.phoneNumbers.size() == 0) {
                        personContact.phoneNumbers.add(phone);
                    }
                }
            }

            contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

As you can see, I used the prevId field, because cursor.moveToNext performs several times for one contact (once for first and last names, one for phone, etc.). After each iteration, I check the previous contact identifier with the current identifier and, if it is false, I update the fields in the personContact model.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution. But this is how I achieved it.

```
ArrayList<String> fnameList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lnameList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mnumList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> hnumList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> wnumList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mailList = new ArrayList<>();

    final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getDynamoDBMapper();
    final ContactsDO firstItem = new ContactsDO(); // Initialize the Notes Object

    firstItem.setUserId(AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getIdentityManager().getCachedUserID());
    String email = null;

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();


    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    // Loop for every contact in the phone
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                Cursor pCur = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{contact_id}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int flag = 0;
                assert pCur != null;
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String mobileNum = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    if (flag == 0) {
                        if(mobileNum!=null){
                        mnumList.add(mobileNum);}
                    } else if (flag == 1) {
                        if(mobileNum!=null){
                            hnumList.add(mobileNum);}
                    } else if (flag == 2) {
                        if(mobileNum!=null){
                            wnumList.add(mobileNum);}
                    }
                    flag++;
                }
                if(flag==1){
                    hnumList.add("");
                    wnumList.add("");
                    Log.e("Set","Both added");
                }
                if(flag==2){
                    wnumList.add("");
                    Log.e("Set","W added");
                }
                pCur.close();


            }
        }
    }
        cursor.close();

                String MIME = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
                String[] params = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                final Cursor nameCur = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        MIME,
                        params,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME);


                assert nameCur != null;
                int i = 0;
                while (nameCur.moveToNext()){
                    String fname = "";
                    String lname = "";
                    fname = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                    lname = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));

                    Log.e("In While","All the time");

                    if(fname!=null){
                        fnameList.add(fname);
                        Log.e("Put","Value Fname "+fname);}
                    if(lname!=null) {
                        lnameList.add(lname);
                        Log.e("Put","Value Lname "+lname);
                    }
                    if(fname==null){
                        fnameList.add(" ");
                    }
                    if(lname==null){
                        lnameList.add(" ");
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                nameCur.close();


        Cursor cursorB = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursorB.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursorB.moveToNext()) {
                // Query and loop for every email of the contact
                String[] paramEmail = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE};
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", paramEmail, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int j=0;
                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
                    mailList.add(email);
                    Log.e("Email",email);
                    j++;
                }
                if(j==0){
                    mailList.add("");
                    Log.e("Email","Dummy Added");
                }
                emailCursor.close();

                output.append("\n");
            }
        }cursorB.close();

        Cursor cursorD = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursorD.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursorD.moveToNext()) {

                String contact_id = cursorD.getString(cursorD.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                //for url

                String newNoteUrl = "";
                String whereName3 = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] whereNameParams3 = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};


                ContentResolver contentResolverUrl = this.getContentResolver();
                try {
                    Cursor cursorUrl = contentResolverUrl.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName3, new String[]{contact_id}, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL);

                    while (cursorUrl.moveToNext()) {
                        newNoteUrl = cursorUrl.getString(cursorUrl.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL));
                        Log.e("URL",newNoteUrl);
                    }
                    Log.e("URL","Not Getting");
                    output.append("\nurl " + newNoteUrl);
                    firstItem.setUrl(newNoteUrl);


                    cursorUrl.close();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }}cursorD.close();

    Log.e("#######","##########################");
    for(int m=0;m<fnameList.size();m++){

        Log.e("Contact Val ",fnameList.get(m)+" , "+lnameList.get(m)+" , "+mnumList.get(m)+" , "+hnumList.get(m)+" , "+wnumList.get(m)+" , "+mailList.get(m));
        ContactsDO item = new ContactsDO();
        item.setUserId(AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getIdentityManager().getCachedUserID());
        item.setFirstName(fnameList.get(m));
        item.setLastName(lnameList.get(m));
        item.setMobileNumber(mnumList.get(m));
        item.setHomeNumber(hnumList.get(m));
        item.setWorkNumber(wnumList.get(m));
        item.setEmail(mailList.get(m));
        try {
            //saving to the database
            dynamoDBMapper.save(item);

        } catch (final AmazonClientException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed saving item : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```